# Set browser display when linking

Tags: html, image

Using `href="image.jpg"` to display an image on a new page, how do I set the `background-color` and center the image on that new page, as part of the `href` call?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.

The only influence a link has over how what it links to is rendered is the `target` attribute, which can hint at a frame or new tab/window.

If you link directly to an image, then it will be rendered according to the browser's standard handling of images.

If you want to control what is rendered around an image, then you have to link to something to render around the image (i.e. an HTML document that you can apply a stylesheet to).